# Is creating a community wiki answer with summary of all posted tiny answers welcome?

Tags: discussion, answers, community-wiki

At times I see questions with single-line answers, that are perhaps more useful as an aggregate. Can I combine all such answers into one, and mark the answer community wiki?

The particular question that triggered this: [K9-like program that blocks websites?](https://askubuntu.com/q/7771/45659)

Answer (score 6):

There is a reason why the answers are left on its own. The better solution, as and when tested by the users, can be voted up and poor and unreliable answers can voted down.

This way, it is easier for everyone to use the best answer when they have a similar question. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: That makes sense, and I probably wont touch those.. :) I'll wait a few days to get more opinions.